# Does the combination of concepts of "cosmic sensorship" and "Gregory-Laflamme instability" correlate with the "string theory"?

Tags: black-hole, space-time

Does the combination of concepts of "cosmic sensorship" and "Gregory-Laflamme instability" correlate with the "string theory" since it appears that both require multidimensional spacetime structure of the universe?

[This link](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/singularities-can-exist-outside-black-holes-in-other-universes/#sa_body) explains in popular terms, meant for unprofessional readership (such as myself), what "cosmic sensorship" is. This link also mentions that the combination of the concepts of "cosmic sensorship" and "Gregory-Laflamme instability" is requiring multidimensional (more than 3) spatial organization of the Universe. Per my knowledge the "string" theory is also assuming multidimensional (more than 3) spatial organization of the Universe.

What I am asking is: whether this similarity of requirements is coincidental or else?

Comment: What are you asking? And how does your link relate to what you're asking? What do you mean by "cosmic censorship"? Are you asking if string theory allows for the existence of naked singularities?.... then ask that question. Please make it abundantly clear what you're asking, so we don't waste our time.

Comment: @Daddy Kropotkin The link, which you apparently didn't read attentively enough, explains in popular terms, meant for unprofessional readership (such as myself), what "cosmic sensorship" is. This link also mentions that concepts of "cosmic sensorship" and "Gregory-Laflamme instability" are requiring multidimensional (more than 3) spatial organization of the Universe.  Per my knowledge the "strings" theory is also assuming multidimensional (more than 3) spatial organization of the Universe. What I am asking is whether this similarity of requirements coincidental or else.

Comment: Nice tone! I actually *did* read the article and found it interesting, but the article does not state your confusion. I don't know if you expect me to read your mind? I don't understand how you have not figured out that you should be putting exactly the information you just provided to me but IN YOUR POST.

Answer (score 3):

The [cosmic censorship hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis) is a very general concept in general relativity that says nothing specific about the number of spacetime dimensions (though I would assume most discussions of assume a standard four-dimensional spacetime) and has nothing to do with string theory; indeed, it really predates the development of string theory itself.

The [Gregory-Laflamme instability](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25350464.pdf), on the other hand, is directly based on string theory and *requires* more than four spacetime dimensions (10, for string theory).